# Hg ( Merculrial ) Backup policy

Tags: mercurial, backup, backup-strategies, rhodecode

We have 500 plus Hg repositories and am looking for a quick and efficient want of backup. Is there a script or Tool that we can use to backup these repositories. We tried Hg bundle, hg clone and regular file system backup but they are not helping.

Is there a standard practice, or some documentation for Hg repositories backup policy?

A follow-up question, what will happen when a user is in a middle of pushing the changeset and we start the backup ?

We do use RhodeCode to publish the Hg repositories.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's no standard.  A true FS-level snapshot taken during a push will be fine, but a non-instantaneous mirroring operation (recursive copy) could end up with a corrupt repo, though it would be repairable to the pre-push state.

In the past I've done something as simple as:

```
for repo in $(find /srv/repos -type d -name .hg | sed 's/\.hg$//') ; do
    hg --cwd $repo --repository $repo push ssh://backupserver/$(basename $repo)
done
```

That pushes all repos to a remote ssh server, incrementally, with full updating-while-pushing integrity, creating them if necessary.

Comment: Thanks Ry4an, We are doing a file system backup. The problem with file system back up is that the recovery takes a lot of time.

Comment: Yeah, you should use clone/push.  I know you said you've tried it in the past, but it's really the way to go.  What didn't work for you?

Comment: It takes a lot of time to back up 500 plus repositories by using the clone/push. Is there a way, we can run the clone/push for these repositories in parallel and not sequentially.

Comment: @RajeevSaraswat What's the problem? Just start the "hg push" commands in parallel rather than sequentially. There's no limitation within Mercurial that prevents you from doing that, it's just a matter of your backup script/tool.

Answer (score 0):

I have a somewhat similar solution of cloning/pulling from a backup server but I trigger the backup on an hg hook.

In the main server global `hgrc`, I have:

```
changegroup.backup = .../backup.sh
```

and in `backup.sh` something like:

```
REPO=`hg root`
ts sshpass -p '...' ssh hg@backupserver "~/bin/pull.exp $REPO" 2>> $LOG
```

Ts (task spooler) allows the operation to happen asynchronously. The expect script is handling the fact that the repository might be new (thus performing an `hg clone --noupdate`) or already existing (thus performing an `hg pull`) and also can give the ssh key a passphrase when requested.

Pushing on the second server is only allowed for the backup hook, so no issue of multiple heads or needed force can happen.

What I find interesting in this type of real time backup is that in case of crash of the main server, it should be much faster to switch to the backup one.